# Copy a single row value and apply it as a column using Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

My `dataset` looks like this:

```
# df1 - minute based dataset

date                  Open
2018-01-01 00:00:00   1.0536 
2018-01-01 00:01:00   1.0527 
2018-01-01 00:02:00   1.0558 
2018-01-01 00:03:00   1.0534 
2018-01-01 00:04:00   1.0524 
...
```

What I want to do is get the value at `05:00:00` `daily` and create a new column called, `OpenVal_5AM` and put that corresponding value on that column. The new `df` will look like this:

```
# df2 - minute based dataset with 05:00:00 Open value

date                  Open     OpenVal_5AM
2018-01-01 00:00:00   1.0536   1.0133 
2018-01-01 00:01:00   1.0527   1.0133 
2018-01-01 00:02:00   1.0558   1.0133
2018-01-01 00:03:00   1.0534   1.0133
2018-01-01 00:04:00   1.0524   1.0133
...
```

Since this is a `minute` based data, we will have `1440` same data point in the new column `OpenVal_5AM` for each day. It is because we are just grabbing the value at a point in time in a day and creating a new column.

**What did I do?**

I used this step:

```
df['OpenVal_5AM'] = df.groupby(df.date.dt.date,sort=False).Open.dt.hour.between(5, 5)
```

That's the closest I could come but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my suggestion:

```
df['OpenVal_5AM'] = df.apply(lambda r: df.Open.loc[r.name.replace(minute=5)], axis=1)
```

Disclaimer: I didn't test it with a huge dataset; so I don't know how it'll perform in that situation.